# AutoMapper with nested entities and different tables

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

[image]

I have the situation above in which I'm receiving a JSON object (PreSalesDTO) with lots of properties and two nested DTOs and I need to map them to the actual models and also store them in different tables. I'm using .NET 7 and AutoMapper to try mapping these classes but I'm struggling a lot with the nested classes.

The typical

```
CreateMap<PreSalesDTO, PreSales>()
```

is not really working, even with the ***ForMember*** option

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. AutoMapper is not something I'm super familiar with.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little weird, but I've tried to implement this; add the following lines to your `MappingProfile`:

```
        CreateMap<PreSalesDto, PreSales>();
        CreateMap<CustomerDto, Customer>();
        CreateMap<PreSalesProductDTO, PreSalesProduct>();

        CreateMap<PreSalesDto, ( PreSales,PreSalesProduct, Customer)>()
            .ForMember(x=>x.Item1,config=>config.MapFrom(src=>new PreSalesDto() {a = src.a,b=src.b,c=src.c}))
            .ForMember(x=>x.Item2,config=>config.MapFrom(src=>src.PreSalesProductDto))
            .ForMember(x => x.Item3, config => config.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerDto));
```

And when I wanted to map wrote the following code:

```
var mapped= _mapper.Map<( PreSales,PreSalesProduct, Customer)>(preSalesDto);
```

`mapped` object is a tuple that `Item1`,`Item2` and `Item3` are `PreSales`, `PreSalesProduct`, and `Customer`,respectively.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'll try to make it clearer: I have this main class (PreSalesDTO) with 2 sub classes in it (PreSalesProductDTO and CustomerDTO) and in this JSON object that I'm receiving via a POST, I need to put everything in it's place accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that  understood your question correctly

you have a class(PreSalesDTO) with 2 subclasses and want to map with similar class(PreSales)

first create MappingProfile with ReverseMap(mapp subclasses)

then create mappingConfig  and use Map to map data

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{

    public MappingProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<PreSales, PreSalesDTO>().ReverseMap();
       
    }

}
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();

// I use NBuilder to CreateList PreSalesDTO
List<PreSalesDTO> fakeReviews = Builder<PreSalesDTO>  .CreateListOfSize(100)
   .All().With(x => x.preSalesProductDTO = Builder<PreSalesProductDTO>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build().ToList())  .With(x => x.customerDTO = Builder<CustomerDTO>.CreateListOfSize(10).Build().ToList()) .Build()  .ToList();

var models = mapper.Map< List<PreSales>>(fakeReviews);
```